# Regular expression to match multiple words with and without whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such object in JavaScript:

```
['abc def ghi', 'abcdef ghi', 'abc DEFghi']
```

I want to match all elements with a regular expression. I have so far:

```
/(abc def ghi)/ig
```

I know about the white space expression such as `\s*`, but is there a way to use it without having to inject it to every whitespace of every element of my object?

Comment: You can first remove all the whitespace from string (replace whitespace with empty string), then match with `(abcdefghi)\ig`

Comment: Is the order of the letters and their number within the string important? Or could it also be something like `dbi aec hfg` or `aaabbb ccc`?

Comment: In my practical scenario it is like follows: I have to compare a string of company names vs one company name, e.g.: `if 'Super Secret Spying CorpInc' in ['Super Secret Spying Corp Inc', 'Another One Inc']` Note the typo "CorpInc"

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with **optional space** matching:

```
var reg = /\babc ?def ?ghi\b/i;
```

`\b` is used for word boundary.

Or you can strip all whitespace beforehand from input and match the string as:

```
var m = input.replace(/\s+/g, "").match(/\babcdefghi\b/i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/abcdefghi/)` If you space is allowed to be anywhere.

If you just want to ignore space in some location, `abc *def *ghi` is short enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `/([a-iA-I\s]+)/ig`

Should match everything in your Object.